# mongo type matching changes when using an index

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to write an automated test to ensure that some fields in my collection have a consistent type across documents. For each of these fields, I have an expected type. So I'm querying for documents that have that field with a different type, ignoring documents where that field is missing or null.

When an index exists on the field, it seems that numeric types 1 (double), 16 (32-bit int) and 18 (64-bit int) are not differentiated. I'm using mongo 2.6.1. Here's a session that demonstrates the problem:

Insert a document into a new collection, it has a single field x which is a 32-bit int:

```
> db.typetest.insert({x:NumberInt(1)})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.typetest.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d52620eb3748b3f9cde293"), "x" : 1 }
```

Note that $type only matches type 16 (32-bit int), as expected:

```
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:1}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:16}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d52620eb3748b3f9cde293"), "x" : 1 }
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:17}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:18}})
```

I need to search for documents that do not match the given type, and $not works as expected:

```
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:1}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d52620eb3748b3f9cde293"), "x" : 1 }
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:2}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d52620eb3748b3f9cde293"), "x" : 1 }
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:16}}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:18}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d52620eb3748b3f9cde293"), "x" : 1 }
```

After creating an index, $type works but $not $type does not differentiate between the 3 numeric types:

```
> db.typetest.ensureIndex({x:1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> 
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:1}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:16}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d52620eb3748b3f9cde293"), "x" : 1 }
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:17}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$type:18}})
> 
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:1}}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:16}}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:18}}})
> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:2}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d52620eb3748b3f9cde293"), "x" : 1 }
```

If this is expected behavior for mongo, that would be good to know. If this is a bug or limitation of mongo, I'd be interested in another way to perform this test. I'd like to avoid using $where (for performance reasons) if possible since these tests will be run quite often on our production database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your negated `$type` queries on MongoDB 2.6.1, 2.6.3, and 2.4.10.

It looks like MongoDB 2.4.10 returns the expected results, but there is a bug in the 2.6 query planner.

Hinting to use an index that doesn't include the field to negate `$type` on works as expected:

```
MongoDB 2.6.3> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:18}}}).hint({_id:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d600acbcad4e0896f33c90"), "x" : 1 }
Fetched 1 record(s) in 1ms

MongoDB 2.6.3> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:18}}}).hint({$natural:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d600acbcad4e0896f33c90"), "x" : 1 }
Fetched 1 record(s) in 1ms

MongoDB 2.6.3> db.typetest.find({x:{$not:{$type:18}}}).hint({x:1})
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
```

I've added your examples in a bug report [SERVER-14706](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14706) which can you watch/upvote.

Comment: perfect - thanks! it's interesting, i actually find this behavior useful sometimes. i wish there was a way to query whether a field is any of the numeric types (1, 16 18). the mongo authors strongly suggest that users don't store different types in the same field, but they don't provide a very rich toolset for ensuring this happens :(.

Comment: @nonagon: I'm not aware of any convenient query shortcut for matching numeric types (although you could always raise a new feature suggestion in the issue tracker at [jira.mongodb.org](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER)). One approach would be to use an `$or` query: `db.typetest.find({$or: [{x: {$type:1}}, {x: {$type:16}}, {x: {$type: 18}} ]})`. In general there shouldn't be an issue with 32-bit vs 64-bit ints - aside from the range of values that can be represented, numeric values will still match in queries.

Comment: You may also find a tool for schema analysis helpful, eg: [Schema.js](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mongodb-schema/). You could use this sort of tool to review field & type coverage (perhaps even storing the schema output before and after your test run so you can diff the results).

Comment: @nonagon: FYI, a fix for the reported issue (SERVER-14706) been committed for MongoDB 2.6.5 (and the 2.7.x development branch).